# Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate must match.

Tags: viewstate

I have a GridView control. When I move the GridView control to another page, I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

How do I tackle with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "change page of gridview control"? are you doing this by code? could you provide some sample of this? are you referring to the fact that you'll get this problem once, when you upload a new aspx, and after that it starts working again?

Answer (score -2):

There may be some cached control. Try clearing your browser cache and try again